# WHMCS, how can I run code only once

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

I have create some functions that are hooked on several WHMCS hooks. Some of my functions are require to be a new table in database that I create for my functionality.

What I like to do is to programmatically create the table into Database, but run the code that generate the table only one time and never run that code again.

Is there any way or a good idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my WHMCS module that I have created, I use the following logic:

```
if(!mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'modulename_%'"))) {

    // there are no tables in the database for our module so we need to create them

}
```

I then use the following to create the database:

```
$createTable[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modulename_table` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;';
```

I have many of these which I then run through a loop:

```
$createTableCount = 0;
for($s=0,$e=count($createTable); $s<$e; $s++){
       $query = mysql_query($createTable[$s]);
       if($query)
            $createTableCount++;
}
```

I then add each column to the table:

```
$alterTable[] = 'ALTER TABLE `modulename_table` ADD `something` int(11) NOT NULL;';
```

which I also run through a loop - this allows me to add new columns/tables and re-run the installation script and add any columns/tables that don't already exist.

Comment: Bat that logic, quering the database each time the user come in the site. I have not create a module, just functions hooked on WHMCS hooks.

Comment: @MerianosNikos you're going to either have to query the database (which you're already connected to) or perhaps check a file (that you can create after db creation). Theres no other way around it unless you provide a standalone installation script.

Comment: Cool ! I will create a file after installation, and then I will check it's existens. Thanks a lot ! :)